# Application of Hahn-Banach Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I am going to quote some versions of Hahn-Banach Theorem and try to deduce a statement which might be wrong.

Thm 1.1 Let $E$ be a real normed vector space and $F\subset E$ as subspace. $\lambda:F\to R$ is bounded linear functional. Then there is $\hat{\lambda}:E\to R$ extends $\lambda$ with same bound.(Proof of this statement is basically done by induction on dimension and application of Zorn lemma.)

Thm 3.1 Let $E$ be a normed vector space, $F\subset E$ subspace and $G$ a complete normed real vector space. Let $\lambda:F\to G$ be a bounded linear map with norm $C$. Then there is a unique extension of $\lambda$ as $\bar{\lambda}:\bar{F}\to G$ where $\bar{F}$ denotes closure of $F$ in $E$ s.t. $\bar{\lambda}$ has the same norm as $\lambda$.(This is essentially done by filling in the missing part by approximation.)

Consider $\lambda:F\to G$ with $F\subset E$ where $E$ is normed vector space, $F$ is subspace of $E$ and $G$ is complete normed real vector space. From Thm 3.1, I deduce $\bar{\lambda}:\bar{F}\to G$ exists and unique. Now I want to further extend $\bar{\lambda}$ to total space $E$. If $G=R$, then one can apply Thm 1.1 without appealing to Thm 3.1.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Can I have $\bar{\lambda}$ extended to $E$ in general with same norm(i.e. $G$ here is no longer $R$ but some banach space)? I doubt this is true. My thought is to "find" orthogonal basis of $G$ but which may not exist. I could pick such a basis and extend corresponding coordinate functions. Then I can put them together. Such kind of procedure will not work if I cannot guarantee sum of extensions of coordinates vanishes for almost all components.

Comment: Same norm?  No.  Try $F=\overline{F}$ $1$-dimensional and $E,G$ $2$-dimensional.

Comment: Particular case: Let $M$ be a vector subspace of a normed space $\mathcal{N}$ (over the same field). So, all $f\in M^*$, the dual of $M$, has an extension $F\in \mathcal{N}^*$ with $||F||=||f||$. Hint to prove: take $p:\mathcal{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ given by $p(\xi)=||f|||\xi|$.